# Plot aggregated variable across two categorical variables

Tags: python, pandas, visualization, data-analysis

I have a dataset of GitHub data with two categorical columns: Repository type and research domain. I want to visualize many variables (booleans and numerical) that showcase the differences across the repository type and research domain, similar to a heatmap or a correlation matrix, like this:
[image]

So I currently have the data in this form:

| faculty | repo_type | stargazers_count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Science | RS | 100 |
| Science | RS | 200 |
| Geosciences | RS | 100 |
| Geosciences | RS | 50 |
| Geosciences | RS | 150 |
| Science | Rscript | 30 |
| Science | Rscript | 10 |
| Geosciences | Rscript | 13 |
| Humanities | RS | 11 |

What I now want is to transform the data in this shape such that I can use seaborn or matplotlib for visualization:

|  | RS | Rscript |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Geoscience | 100 | 13 |
| Science | 150 | 20 |
| Humanities | 11 | - |

I was thinking to use groupby followed by pivot but that doesn't really make sense. Can you point me towards how I'd achieve this data transformation?

Comment: I think this question is more suited for stackoverflow

Comment: Thanks, I'll ask it there after the 90 minute post limit has passed

Comment: Using a simple [`.pivot()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) should do the trick: `df.pivot(index="faculty", columns="repo_type", values="stargazers_count")`

Comment: @Oxbowerce thanks, that raised an error which was fixed by using pivot_table instead. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46528599/pandas-pivot-produces-valueerror-index-contains-duplicate-entries-cannot-resh